# How can I start a brand new request in Scrapy crawler?

Tags: http, scrapy, web-crawler

I am scraping from a website that will give every request session a `sid`, after getting the `sid`, I perform further search query with this `sid` and scrape the results.

I want to change the `sid` every time I've finished scraping all results of a single query, I've tried clearing the cookies but it doesn't work.

However, if I restart my crawler, it wll get a different `sid` each time, I just don't know how to get a new `sid` without restart the crawler.

I am wondering if there're something else that let the server know two requests are from the same connection.

Thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['xxx.com']
    start_urls = ['http://xxx/']

    sid_pattern = r'SID=(\w+)&'
    SID = None
    query_list = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
    i = 0

    def parse(self, response):
        if self.i >= len(self.query_list):
            return
        pattern = re.compile(self.sid_pattern)
        result = re.search(pattern, response.url)
        if result is not None:
            self.SID = result.group(1)
        else:
            exit(-1)

        search_url = 'http://xxxx/AdvancedSearch.do'            
        query = self.query_list[i]
        self.i += 1

        query_form = {
            'aaa':'bbb'
        }

        yield FormRequest(adv_search_url, method='POST', formdata=query_form, dont_filter=True,
                          callback=self.parse_result_entry)
        yield Request(self.start_urls[0], cookies={}, callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)

    def parse_result(self, response):
        do something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting COOKIES_ENABLED = False can achieve this, but is there another way other than a global settings?